# import query shows extra varchar type

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a CSV file into phpMyAdmin.  The file has four columns, however, the import query shows an extra varchar type with no associated column name.  This is the query generated by phpMyAdmin:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name`.`TABLE 4` 
 (
  `Column1` varchar(3), 
  `Column2` varchar(3), 
  `Column3` varchar(5), 
  `Column4` varchar(1049),  
  varchar(1)   --This is extra
 ) 
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Thats because you have a fifth `varchar(1)` at the end. Remove that from the table definition.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, the query is generated phpMyAdmin dynamically. and user2948954 is asking why this `varchar(1)` is being generated.

Comment: Somewhere along the line, you added that column. Perhaps accidentally.

Comment: In my first import attempt, I imported the file.  I then attempted importing just the data, and although the CSV file only has 4 columns, the import failed, the error message gave me invalid column count.  Will revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Despite a visual check, I could not find any data in any other column beyond column4.  So I deleted columns 5,6 and 7.  My next import attempt was successful.  Strange.